# Search for a special number vb.net

Tags: vb.net, string, text, browser

I have a webpage full of numbers like:

```
xxxx.xxx.xxx.xxx[space]xx
```

E.g.:

```
124.240.187.79 82
```

How do I search and get them programatically?

Comment: Use a regular expression.

Comment: Like? That's why I posted the question

Comment: We're not just going to do _all_ the thinking for you. [Have you tried anything yourself?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: I don't think it's a 100 line long expression. I just can't fiugure out how to do this. And yes, I try everything before I post a question

Comment: You're asking for too much at once. We need a starting place. Are you able to load the page into memory? If so, what does the code to do that look like? If not, what do you have so far that doesn't work, and in what way does it fail.

Answer (score 0):

regexp03.vbs:

```
Dim objRegExp    : Set objRegExp = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
objRegExp.Global = True
Dim input
input = "I have a webpage full of numbers like: xxxx.xxx.xxx.xxx[space]xx E.g.: 124.240.187.79 82 How do I search and get them programatically?"

Dim Pattern : Pattern = "[0-9]{3}\.[0-9]{3}\.[0-9]{3}\.[0-9]{2}\s[0-9]{2}"
WScript.Echo "Pattern : " & Pattern

objRegExp.Pattern = Pattern

Set objMatches = objRegExp.Execute(input)

For i=0 To objMatches.Count-1
  Set objMatch = objMatches.Item(i)
  WScript.Echo objMatch.Value
Next
```

command line:

```
cscript //nologo regexp03.vbs
```

Output:

```
Pattern : [0-9]{3}\.[0-9]{3}\.[0-9]{3}\.[0-9]{2}\s[0-9]{2}
124.240.187.79 82
```

Comment: @user2023328 Search for how to use regular expressions in VB.Net STTR has given you the pattern